# How to pause PUSH messages until the socket has a client with ZeroMQ?

Tags: sockets, message-queue, zeromq, pyzmq, netmq

I am using ZeroMQ and NetMQ to allow for a two-way communication between some python scripts and a Unity C# script. I implemented it with two PUSH-PULL sockets, one for each way. This works fine. The problem I now have is that I want to stop or pause sending messages from the python server when there is nobody pulling these messages.

I read that ZeroMQ does not allow any native API calls to manage the Queue or something like that, but I could try setting the ZMQ_SNDHWM to something like 1. The problem is that I don't care about older state and the push socket would mute any outgoing messages if the high water mark is met.

> When a ZMQ_PUSH socket enters the mute state due to having reached the high water mark for all downstream nodes, or if there are no downstream nodes at all, then any zmq_send operations on the socket shall block until the mute state ends or at least one downstream node becomes available for sending; messages are not discarded.Is there a way to detect if someone is pulling the messages or if someone is connected to the socket and otherwise pause or flush the queue?
> ~ https://libzmq.readthedocs.io/en/zeromq3-x/zmq_socket.html

Thanks in advance.

```
controls_socket = zmq.Context().socket(zmq.PUSH)
controls_socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5556")

while is_running:
  [...]
  controls_socket.send_string(control_commands)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ZMQ_CONFLATE` (zmq.CONFLATE) socket option. This ignores the HWMs and only keeps the last/latest message sent/received in the buffer.

NOTE:

- You need to set ZMQ_CONFLATE before calling `connect()/bind()`
- It does not support multipart messages.

Comment: And would it be best to set this option for both PULL and PUSH for both sides? Because I have one PULL and PUSH socket in Python and C#. Or would it be enough to set it just in the responisble PUSH sockets?

Comment: If you only ever want the very latest message on the PULL socket and don't care if you miss some messages (e.g if not polling/receiving fast enough) then set CONFLATE on PULL also.   Remember CONFLATE reduces the buffer to 1 frame. It really depends on how your system is expected to work.